# Getting user input in bakground of a process in wxpython

Tags: wxpython

I am trying to write a code in wxpython where a process is run in the front and at the same time user inputs can manipulate in which direction the process goes.

For example, if I am playing a song, please tell me how can I code that I use widgets(buttons) to stop pause the song.

Answer (score 0):

The wxPython demo has a good example of creating a media player using `wx.media`. I also wrote an [example program](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/04/20/wxpython-creating-a-simple-mp3-player/) to play MP3's using this control.

This [article](http://blog.tankorsmash.com/?p=321) also demonstrates how to play a music file with wxPython, although the example is a bit unorthodox.